# Why did I get my bounty back?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty, deleted-questions

I have created a bounty on the below question

https://stackoverflow.com/q/51323486/6633337

But I didn't find a suitable answer to donate the bounty to during the bounty period and it expired without going to anyone.

I know that I will not receive the bounty back unless you provide it to someone.

Strangely, I have got my bounty back this morning.

Why did I get my bounty back?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> Can anyone tell the reason for bounty back...

Simple answer the question is deleted that's why your bounty reputation is refunded

**FYI**

**February 2018**, [the rules have changed:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306966/changes-to-bounty-rules-removal-of-double-rep-retention-blocking-of-owner-dele?cb=1)

> - If the bounty awardee does not get to keep the reputation, or if there was no answer that earned any bounty rep, the reputation is
>     refunded. It can take a few minutes for this to happen. If the
>     question is undeleted or migration is rejected, the reputation is
>     deducted again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I taught that bounty will not get back once applied

Comment: What changed in February are that in *fewer* cases the bounty is refunded. The bounty would have been refunded before that time too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Can't this be utilized as a fraud then? I raise a bounty on my question - wait for good answer - when I get one, I delete the question (without awarding bounty and accepting answer) - I get my reputation back. This way, I get my answer as well as my reputation points. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AmitJoshi - isn't that addressed in the linked question/answer? You can't delete a question with an active bounty, and if the author awards the bounty they can't delete either.

Comment: @AmitJoshi If any answer has been upvoted, even if it's total score is < 0, or if there's more than one answer, then the question OP can't delete the question. There is a possible, but unlikely period, where the bounty has expired, but is not awarded, where the question OP could delete the question, if there was only one answer which had not been upvoted. For more detail on deletion see: the question inked in the answer and [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: @AmitJoshi: You can't just delete questions with upvoted answers. This post was deleted by the community, which requires a) users with enough reputation to vote to delete and b) enough such users to meet the deletion criteria. That's not something that an individual can just line up to abuse. And when the bounty-awarded answer has a score of 3 or up and is at least 60 days old, the bounty isn't refunded at all even when the answer is deleted.

Comment: @AmitJoshi: (technically, it's the deletion of the *answer* that triggers the bounty refund, IIRC. Bounty-awarded answers have a higher likelyhood of being marked accepted, which makes it harder for them to be deleted).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: can we change the help text then? This is totally new for me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: @ThomasWeller: it’s an edge case, it’s not a refund but the normal process of post deletion handling. Posts with awarded bounties are less likely to be deleted however, and I don’t think we need to clutter the help pages with this much detail about what happens when a post is deleted or undeleted again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "Edge" cases are cases. Saying how things work is not "clutter".

Comment: @philipxy the help center needs to be concise, it doesn’t have to cover all cases. Edge cases are clutter there as the vast majority of site users will not see ever encounter this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There needs to be a clear description of how things work--the user manual. Ok, not the help. Where then?  SO chronically fails to "WTFM". It works via turk googling, but that is inadequate for communcating how an interface behaves.

Comment: @philipxy: sure, in the FAQ posts on Meta ([central](https://meta.stackexchange.com), and here where applicable) where this is [already covered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).